# Simple Shiny Module with dataframe and column as parameters not working

Tags: r, shiny

I am still strugling trying to understand shiny modules. Below a simple example I can not make to work:

```
# MODULE UI
bsc_test_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textOutput(ns("test"))
}

# MODULE Server
bsc_test_OUT <- function(input, output, session, df, var) {
  output$test <- renderText({
    x <- mean(df$var, na.rm=T)
    t <- paste0(var, "=", x)
  })
}

# App ui 
ui <- fluidPage(
        bsc_test_UI("test_1"), 
        bsc_test_UI("test_2"), 
        bsc_test_UI("test_3")
        )

# App server
server <- function(input, output,session){  
  callModule(bsc_test_OUT, "test_1", mtcars, 'cyl')
  callModule(bsc_test_OUT, "test_2", mtcars, 'mpg')
  callModule(bsc_test_OUT, "test_3", iris, 'Sepal.Length')
}

# App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It is supossed to print the mean of the variable "var" of the dataframe "df", but it does not work.

This is the ouput:

```
cyl=NA
mpg=NA
Sepal.Length=NA
```

I tried to put the var name without quotqtions, with no success. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `df$var` with `df[,var]`, and it works

```
library(shiny)
# MODULE UI
bsc_test_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textOutput(ns("test"))
}

# MODULE Server
bsc_test_OUT <- function(input, output, session, df, var) {
  output$test <- renderText({
    x <- mean(df[,var], na.rm=T)
    t <- paste0(var, "=", x)
  })
}

# App ui 
ui <- fluidPage(
  bsc_test_UI("test_1"), 
  bsc_test_UI("test_2"), 
  bsc_test_UI("test_3")
)

# App server
server <- function(input, output,session){  
  callModule(bsc_test_OUT, "test_1", mtcars, 'cyl')
  callModule(bsc_test_OUT, "test_2", mtcars, 'mpg')
  callModule(bsc_test_OUT, "test_3", iris, 'Sepal.Length')
}

# App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```